How to correct for PowerShell ISE string issue with external command on Windows 11
I have a PowerShell script (targeting 5.1) which when run using PowerShell ISE on Windows 10 works fine but in Windows 11 fails. The script pipes string literals to sqlite3.exe, for example
".show" | & .\sqlite3.exe db

Successful output on Windows 10:

    echo: off
     eqp: off
 explain: auto
 headers: off
    mode: list    nullvalue: ""
  output: stdout colseparator: "|" rowseparator: "\n"
   stats: off
   width:
filename: db


Output on Windows 11:

sqlite3.exe : Parse error near line 1: near ".": syntax error At
line:1 char:11
+ ".show" | & .\sqlite3.exe db
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Parse error nea...": syntax error:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
ï»¿.show
^--- error here

So it appears from the last 2 lines that ISE is adding what I assume is a byte-order mark to the beginning of the string which sqlite3.exe cannot handle.
I realise the obvious option is tell users to just not run it in ISE but I was wondering if there was any way of configuring ISE or rewriting the script to avoid the error?

The PowerShell ISE is no longer in active feature development. As a shipping component of Windows, it continues to be officially supported for security and high-priority servicing fixes. We currently have no plans to remove the ISE from Windows.. Anyways, I think this helpful answer might help to resolve the issue.

@iRon thanks. Unfortunately ISE is the default application on Windows 11 for opening .ps1 files (on the image that our IT is using anyway) so I'd rather it "just work" if possible

I am not familiar with the external .\sqlite3.exe command, but have you tried single quotes and applying it as an argument:,something like: & .\sqlite3.exe db '.show'.

& .\sqlite3.exe db '.show' (either single or double quotes) works! Not sure why I did it the pipe way in the first place. Anyway - if you add that as an answer I'll mark it as the solution

The command works fine in a standard PowerShell window and Visual Studio Code's command window, which is why I think it is ISE.

(Happy to see that it has been resolved for you) "if you add that as an answer I'll mark it as the solution". I was just shooting from the hip based on some general PowerShell piping / external command (line) best practices but I don't have a good understanding of the actual cause of the different behavors you defined (as Windows 10/11 etc.). Therefore I will leave it up to somebody else to write an adequate answer to this...

tl;dr

Either: Bypass the problem by passing .show as an argument (rather than via the pipeline) to sqlite3.exe, as iRon suggests (note that I'm omitting &, the caller operator, as it isn't necessary here):
.\sqlite3.exe db .show


Or: Fix the character-encoding problem, in the simplest case as follows, but note that this only works for ASCII-characters-only text:
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding
'.show' | .\sqlite3.exe db


See below for details and a UTF-8 alternative.




Indeed, the Windows PowerShell ISE is best avoided (to add to iRon's helpful comment on the question):

It is no longer actively developed and there are reasons not to use it (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is Visual Studio Code with its PowerShell extension.

Its poor support for calling external programs, such as sqlite3.exe, is one of the reasons to avoid it, and you've run into one aspect of it:

Inexplicably, the $OutputEncoding preference variable defaults to UTF-8 in Windows 11; in Windows 10, it was - more sensibly - the system's active ANSI encoding, in sync with [Console]::OutputEncoding.

In a regular Windows PowerShell console, it defaults to ASCII(!), which is equally mystifying. In PowerShell 7, it defaults to BOM-less UTF-8, which - while better due to not using a BOM - is also mystifying: see next point.

Given that console windows (as well as Windows Terminal tabs and Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal (I won't mention these explicitly below), but not the console emulation built into the ISE) default to the system's active legacy OEM code page, whose encoding is reflected in [Console]::OutputEncoding (which PowerShell uses to decode external-program output), it would make sense to default $OutputEncoding to the same code page (encoding).

Also inexplicably, the ISE defaults to the ANSI code page instead, resulting in different default behavior between it and console windows.

This despite the fact that external programs will see the system's OEM code page as the active one (run chcp to verify), so that any non-ASCII characters in an external program's output will be misinterpreted by PowerShell in the ISE.


What's worse, $OutputEncoding in the ISE is - inappropriately - a UTF-8 encoding with BOM, which is what causes your problem - see below.





Because $OutputEncoding is a UTF-8 encoding with  BOM in the ISE by default, any data you send via the pipeline to an external program will have a BOM prepended - which most external programs do NOT expect, including sqlite3.exe, causing them to interpret the 3 bytes that comprise the BOM as part of the text.
Because [Console]::OutputEncoding in the ISE is the active ANSI code page, and PowerShell uses it to decode stdout and stderr output from external programs, it mis-decodes the UTF-8 BOM contained in sqlite3.exe's stderr output before the word .show (sqlite3.exe assumes a fixed encoding of UTF-8, but doesn't recognize a BOM): The UTF-8 BOM is composed of 3 bytes, 0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf, which is mis-decoded as string ï»¿ (i.e. 3 characters) if the active ANSI code page is Windows-1252, such as in US-English.[1]

Solution options:
Do one of the following before calling sqlite3.exe:

Align $OutputEncoding with [Console]::OutputEncoding, which sends text in the same ANSI encoding that well-behaved external console programs expect - however, due to the mismatch between the ANSI encoding the ISE uses vs. the OEM encoding used by external programs, this solution is effective only if the input text as well as the external program's output is composed of ASCII-range characters only or if the target program happens to use the active ANSI code page, as python does, for instance. (This in effect restores the Windows 10 behavior.)
# Effective only for all-ASCII-characters input and output text.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding


Switch the session to using BOM-less UTF-8 consistently, which enables full Unicode support on both the input and output side:
chcp >$null # dummy command that forces allocation of a console
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new()


Note the need to execute a dummy command that calls a console application (chcp) in order to ensure that the ISE has allocated a console behind the scenes; without that, assigning to [Console]::InputEncoding or [Console]::OutputEncoding would cause an error.
(Also, using chcp 65001 directly to change the active code page to UTF-8 would not work, because .NET caches the encodings stored in [Console]::InputEncoding and [Console]::OutputEncoding.)

See this answer for background information.





[1] You can verify this as follows: [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252).GetString( [System.Text.UTF8Encoding]::new($true).GetPreamble())

In Dutch we have a saying: "de klok hebben horen luiden maar niet weten waar de klepel hangt" which really applied to me in this case. @saviourofdp, I think you got your full answer here, and I recommend to  accept that.

Thank you, @iRon. I realized that I had missed another problematic aspect of the ISE, making the $OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding quick fix effective only for ASCII-range characters: The ISE defaults to ANSI, whereas any external programs default to OEM. I've updated the answer accordingly.

@mklement0 great answer, thank you

Windows 10 22H2 ISE:
$outputencoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : iso-8859-1
EncodingName      : Western European (Windows)
HeaderName        : Windows-1252
WebName           : Windows-1252
WindowsCodePage   : 1252
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 1252

Windows 11 22H2 ISE:
$outputencoding

BodyName          : utf-8
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8)
HeaderName        : utf-8
WebName           : utf-8
WindowsCodePage   : 1200
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : True
IsMailNewsSave    : True
IsSingleByte      : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 65001

One way to set it to the old encoding:
$outputencoding = [text.encoding]::default

'.show' | .\sqlite3.exe file1.sql

        echo: off
         eqp: off
     explain: auto
     headers: off
        mode: list
   nullvalue: ""
      output: stdout
colseparator: "|"
rowseparator: "\n"
       stats: off
       width: 
    filename: file1.sql

The utf8 encoding doesn't seem to bother piping to external commands like findstr or find...
'.show' | findstr /l .show

.show


'.show' | find '".show"'

.show


'hi' | findstr ^...hi$  # allow for BOM chars

hi


very helpful, thanks

Good to have confirmation that the behavior changed between Windows 10 and 11. findstr and find look for substrings, so that the presence of the extraneous BOM isn't a problem; note that it is there, as the following command demonstrates (when run in the ISE on W11):  '.show' | cmd /c 'findstr /l .show >out.txt'; Format-Hex out.txt. Curiously, though, PowerShell seems to remove it when captured an external program's output.
